# SVG icon does not highlight in drop-down menu Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, svg, menu

I am trying to achieve the same pink highlight in the accessories' menu option (the one at the bottom). For some reason, the "sock" icon is not highlighted in pink. Any ideas?
Website --> https://pinky.bg/

The SVG code of the properly highlighting icon Example ->[image]

The code below is of the properly highlighting SVG in pink

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="14" viewBox="0 0 18 14" fill="none">
<path d="M13.8128 2.46322V0H4.15V2.54819L0 12.1176L0.210798 12.3016C0.290257 12.371 2.23431 14 8.99967 14C15.7653 14 17.7097 12.371 17.7892 12.3016L18 12.1176L13.8128 2.46322ZM4.8933 0.760031H13.0695V2.17259H4.8933V0.760031ZM15.5934 12.4793C13.4999 13.108 10.8522 13.24 9 13.24C7.14749 13.24 4.4998 13.108 2.40645 12.4793C1.64001 12.2491 1.16976 12.0173 0.919753 11.8717L4.79641 2.93262H6.50814L5.64566 6.84822L6.37082 7.01524L7.27006 2.93262H10.6928L11.592 7.01524L12.3172 6.84822L11.4547 2.93262H13.2033L17.0802 11.8717C16.8302 12.0173 16.3599 12.2491 15.5934 12.4793Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
</svg>
```

The SVg that is causing me troubles is

```
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 25.2.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="17px" height="18.9px" viewBox="0 0 17 18.9" enable-background="new 0 0 17 18.9">
<path d="M7.5,18.9c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.1-0.8-0.2c-1.2-0.4-1.9-1.2-2.3-2.3c0,0,0-0.1-0.1-0.2c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0c-1.7,0.1-3.2-1-3.8-2.6  c-0.5-1.6,0.2-3.4,1.6-4.2c1.2-0.7,2.4-1.4,3.5-2c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.2-0.3c0-0.9,0-1.8,0-2.6c0-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4  c0.1,0,0.3,0,0.4,0c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3c0,1,0,2,0,3c0,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.4C5,8.4,4.1,8.9,3.2,9.5C3.1,9.5,3.1,9.5,3,9.6  c1,1.7,2,3.4,3,5.1c0.2-0.1,0.5-0.3,0.7-0.4c0.4-0.2,0.7-0.4,1.1-0.6c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c-0.4-1.8,0-3.3,1.2-4.6  C9.9,8,10.9,7.6,12,7.5c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0-2.3,0-4.5,0-6.8c-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.9,0c0,0.3,0,0.6,0,0.9c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3  c0,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.3c-0.2,0-0.3-0.2-0.3-0.4c0-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.9c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2c-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.9,0c0,0.4,0,0.7,0,1.1  c0,0.3-0.3,0.5-0.5,0.4C8.9,2.1,8.8,2,8.8,1.8c0-0.3,0-0.7,0-1.1c-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.9,0c0,0.3,0,0.6,0,0.9c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2  c0,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.3C7.3,2.2,7.1,2,7.1,1.8c0-0.4,0-0.7,0-1.1c-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.9,0c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3c0,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.4  c-0.2,0-0.4-0.2-0.4-0.4c0-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.7C5.5,0.1,5.6,0,5.9,0c0.9,0,1.7,0,2.6,0c1.3,0,2.6,0,3.9,0c0.4,0,0.5,0.1,0.5,0.5  c0,0.7,0,1.4,0,2.2c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0c1.2,0,2.3,0,3.5,0c0.3,0,0.5,0.1,0.5,0.5c0,3,0,5.9,0,8.9c0,1.5-0.7,2.6-2,3.3  c-1.7,1-3.4,1.9-5.1,2.9c-0.5,0.3-1.1,0.5-1.7,0.6c0,0,0,0,0,0C8,18.9,7.7,18.9,7.5,18.9z M12.9,3.4c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3  c0,1.9,0,3.8,0,5.6c0,1.4-0.6,2.5-1.9,3.3c-0.8,0.5-1.5,0.9-2.3,1.3c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4,0.2c0.6,1.1,1.2,2.1,1.8,3.1  c0.7-0.4,1.3-0.7,1.9-1.1c-0.4-1.5-0.2-2.8,0.6-4.1c0.9-1.2,2.1-1.9,3.6-2c0-2.3,0-4.5,0-6.8c-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.9,0c0,0.3,0,0.7,0,1  c0,0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.1c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.3-0.4c0-0.4,0-0.7,0-1.1C14,3.4,13.4,3.4,12.9,3.4z M2.3,9.9  c-1,0.6-1.5,1.4-1.6,2.5c0,1.2,0.5,2.1,1.5,2.7c1,0.5,2,0.5,3-0.1C4.3,13.4,3.3,11.7,2.3,9.9z M12.7,15.8c0,0,0.1,0,0.1-0.1  c0.7-0.4,1.3-0.8,2-1.2c0.4-0.2,0.7-0.5,1-0.9c0.6-0.8,0.5-1.8,0.5-2.7C13.8,11,12,13.5,12.7,15.8z M8.5,13.2  C8.6,13.1,8.6,13.1,8.5,13.2c0.8-0.4,1.5-0.8,2.2-1.2c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.5-0.4c1-0.9,1-2.1,0.9-3.3C9.8,8.3,7.8,10.6,8.5,13.2z   M7.6,14.6c-0.9,0.5-1.7,1-2.6,1.5c0.5,1.9,2.8,2.7,4.4,1.6C8.8,16.7,8.2,15.6,7.6,14.6z"></path>
<path d="M5.5,2.8c0-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.4-0.4c0.2,0,0.4,0.2,0.4,0.4C6.2,3,6,3.1,5.8,3.1C5.6,3.1,5.5,3,5.5,2.8z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: the difference is that in the first 2 svg elements the paths have a `fill="currentColor"` attribute. The paths of the last svg element lack this attribute.

Comment: I noticed this and tried editing the code for for the problematic SVG, however it disappears completely.

Comment: Buddy, you are right, I just solved the issue. Thank you very much! I just added fill="currentColor" at the end of each path.